# execute export command to current terminal using python

Tags: python, shell, operating-system, subprocess, export

I want to set environment in current terminal using python. I have tried below method but they all are executing in subterminal.

Ex 1 - `export OpenCV_DIR=/home/root/cv_install/share/OpenCV/`

I tried ::
a) `os.environ['OpenCV_DIR'] = "/home/root/cv_install/share/OpenCV/"`
b) `subprocess.run("export OpenCV_DIR=/home/root/cv_install/share/OpenCV/", shell=True)`
c) `os.system("export OpenCV_DIR=/home/root/cv_install/share/OpenCV/", shell=True)`

None of the above listed method worked for me. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried

```
shell=True
```

it will help you it will enable command to be enabled in shell

```
subprocess.run("export OpenCV_DIR=/home/root/cv_install/share/OpenCV/", shell=True)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but didn't work for me. Thanks for your time.